# allHeaderFields is not case insensitive when looking up keys

Tags: swift, header, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to make my API calls.

Depending on the server I'm using the response headers could be capitalized.

But as the documentation says for allHeaderFields :

> var allHeaderFields: [AnyHashable : Any] { get }
>
> A dictionary containing all the HTTP header fields received as part of the server’s response. By examining this dictionary clients can see the “raw” header information returned by the HTTP server.
>
> The keys in this dictionary are the header field names, as received from the server. See RFC 2616 for a list of commonly used HTTP header fields.
>
> HTTP headers are case insensitive. To simplify your code, certain header field names are canonicalized into their standard form. For example, if the server sends a content-length header, it is automatically adjusted to be Content-Length.
>
> The returned dictionary of headers is configured to be case-preserving during the set operation (unless the key already exists with a different case), and case-insensitive when looking up keys.
>
> For example, if you set the header X-foo, and then later set the header X-Foo, the dictionary’s key will be X-foo, but the value will taken from the X-Foo header.

But in my code if I'm doing this :

```
if let headers = response.response?.allHeaderFields {
   print("Access-Token: \(response.response?.allHeaderFields["Access-Token"])")
   print("access-token: \(response.response?.allHeaderFields["access-token"])")
   print("access-token: \(response.response?.allHeaderFields["Access-token"])")
}
```

In the console I have

```
Access-Token: nil
access-token: Optional(jdRtDzKHNs_i-jt3Lh3a3A)
access-token: nil
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is not related with Alamofire. This is a Swift bug.

Unfortunately this is a known bug that appeared at Swift 3 when they transformed the headers into Dictionary. The bug is registered since 2016 and remains unsolved. To make things worst they not even corrected the  Swift documentation.

This is a violation of the HTTP specification and I have no idea why they flagged  this only as a Medium priority. Seems that they do not care and will never solve this problem.

[A workaround was made by Stephen Gurnett](http://www.stephen-gurnett.org/unlikely-objects/2017/2/1/fylkgu09vo4g3zhofzyv9gucz64alt)

[Bug Report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2429)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and pointing out that this is very unfortunate. Which is indeed. :/
As of Swift 4.2, it's not yet fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple finally provided a way to do case-insensitive lookups for HTTP headers in Swift. We should call:

```
HTTPURLResponse.value(forHTTPHeaderField:)
```

for that instead of using `allHeaderFields`. You can find this info [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2429) (that's the bug report link provided by Eduardo Vital in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

following extension works for all condition. as NSDictionary will avoid convert to swfit dictionary, and keep the case insensitive Dictionary.

```swift
extension HTTPURLResponse {
    /// get value for caseless header field
    public final func headerString(field: String) -> String? {
        return (self.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary)[field] as? String
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this castless feature disappears when using optional types.

so following all works:

```swift
(self.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary)["Access-Token"]
(self.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary)["access-token"]
(self.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary)["aCCESS-toKEN"]
```

but following not works:

```swift
(self.allHeaderFields as? NSDictionary)?["aCCESS-toKEN"]
```